# Why does "docker push" push several images and where?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have private repo on docker hub named `alek/test`.
On my Mac:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
alek/test           0.1                 dc1a7cc41129        33 minutes ago      643 MB
node                0.12.7              9e20baae42c8        5 days ago          641.6 MB

$ docker push alek/test
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/alek/test] (len: 1)
dc1a7cc41129: Image successfully pushed 
537a913fe639: Image successfully pushed 
b40236e9037f: Image successfully pushed 
53c8b1d50397: Image successfully pushed 
e8c37c1e2189: Image successfully pushed 
68bbfd9543a7: Image successfully pushed 
9e20baae42c8: Image already exists 
8b74d7a75802: Image successfully pushed 
3383909e8f95: Image already exists 
e0919a8b95a8: Image already exists 
6ad0799af6bd: Image successfully pushed 
9213e81cb0f2: Image successfully pushed 
607e965985c1: Image successfully pushed 
1ff9f26f09fb: Image successfully pushed 
9a61b6b1315e: Image already exists 
902b87aaaec9: Image successfully pushed 
0.1: digest: sha256:a2b1d8a3b283f13e8d6a1407e886ca8ee62d93377949e050b9e05509ce6aaf86 size: 30568
```

What just have happened??? Why several images have been pushed? Also where they were actually pushed - nothing changed on my private repo on docker hub (screen).

[image]

I am not sure If I understand docker hub correctly.
What I want is to build image from Dockerfile and push it to my repo to make it available for a client to pull it on his side and run in container...

Comment: Can you show the contents of the **Tags** tab? As the screenshot goes, it's in **Repo Info** tab.

Comment: Well now it contains proper tags after pushing with `:<tag>`. But before, after pushing without `:<tag>` part, "tags" tab was not showing anything...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You understand correctly.

There is an image for each layer in the image, corresponding to each instruction in a Dockerfile. Docker pushes these layers independently.

As you didn't specify a tag, Docker will push all the tags in the repository (in this case just 0.1). Anyone with access to your repository should be able to download it with `docker pull alek/test:0.1`. If you look at the `tags` tab on the Hub, you should see your images there.

If you do a `docker push` without a tag, I think it pushes the whole repo - i.e. all the images. If you do `docker run` or `docker pull` without a tag, it will use the `latest` tag. So I assume the `0.1` tag got pushed in your case, but you would need to say `docker pull alek/test:0.1` to pull it.

Comment: It seems that adding a tag to command `docker push alek/test` -> `docker push alek/test:0.1` worked - I can see 0.1 tag in repo. But what happened before without a tag? images have been uploaded somwhere - are they still there?

Comment: If you don't supply a tag, it assumes a tag of `latest`.

Comment: As you can see in my question I don't have image tagged "latest". Also docker repo did not show any tags. Maybe it's a bug and it shouldn't upload anything if tag has not been specified and there isnt image tagged "latest"?

Comment: No, it's expected to push the whole repository and all images. It's not very symmetrical with pull, but it's not a bug.

Comment: The problem is that after push "Tags" tab in my repo DID NOT show ANY tags, as if repo was EMPTY. That's why I've created this question here. I was expecting that I will find tag `0.1` in my repo (see my question and `docker images` output).

Comment: Yeah, you should have been able to see all tags I think. Possibly a bug or caching issue.